# Как сделать передачу параметров в POST-запросе из form без input?

Tags: javascript, java, html, post, form

Существует ли способ в данном случае передать параметры в POST form без использования input?

Всё просто - ссылка в моей ситуации служит как кнопка, после ее нажатия нужно считать определенные параметры в Java.

```
 <form method="POST" id="my_form">
      <table>
           <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();" class="editmentordiv" name="ws">Name Surname</a></td>
           </tr>
      </table>
 </form>
```

Считывание параметров в Java:

```
if (method.equals("POST")) {

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpExchange.getRequestBody(), "utf-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String formData = br.readLine();
    Map inputs = parseFormData(formData);

    String first_parametr = inputs.get("parametr_name").toString();
```

Comment: Какие определённые параметры? Пока что ничего не понятно, а также непонятно, что для ваших «определённых параметров» мешает добавить инпуты

Comment: Если вы не отвечаете на вопросы, то вам вряд ли смогут помочь. Если вопрос решён, то напишите ответ самому себе с описанием решения.